# Why have a function with an_arg_name and *args as parameters instead of just *args

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why have a function as `my_fun(an_arg, *arg)` or even this `a_func(dict=None, **args)` why do people prefer to do this instead of saying just `my_func(*args)`? Are we not just repeating ourselves by using the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to help give your function a bit more meaning. Let's say that I'm trying to take in a function that increments a list of numbers by some parameter. Here's a silly example to illustrate:

```
def increase(increment, *nums):
    return [num + increment for num in nums]
```

In this case, it's very clear what the first argument does, and what it's used for. In contrast, if we did this:

```
def increase(*args):
    return [num + args[0] for num in args[1:]]
```

...then it's less clear what we're doing, and what all the arguments do.

In addition, it's also useful if we want to take in data, transform it, and pass in the rest of my arguments to another function.

Here's another contrived example:

```
def log(message, func, *args):
    print message
    func(*args)
```

Once again, if we just used only `*args`, our meaning is less clear:

```
def log(*args):
    print args[0]
    args[1](args[2:])
```

This would be much more error-prone, and hard to modify. It would also cause the function to fail if there weren't enough arguments -- by doing it the first way, you essentially make the first two elements mandatory and the rest optional.

Answer (score 2):

There's difference between `my_fun(an_arg, *arg)` and `my_func(*args)`.

```
my_fun(an_arg, *arg)
```

Pass at least 1 argument or more arguments.

```
my_func(*args)
```

Pass any number of arguments, even **0**.

**Demo:**

```
>>> def my_fun(an_arg, *arg):
    pass
... 
>>> def my_fun1(*arg):
    pass
... 
>>> my_fun()
... 
TypeError: my_fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'an_arg'

>>> my_fun1(1) #works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

They aren't equivalent forms. The other "repeat" forms bind arguments to discreet parameters and, more importantly, indicate that some parameters are required. Try to call `def my_fun(an_arg, *arg): pass` with 0 arguments.

While discreet (known) parameters work in many cases, `*args` allows for ["sequence-variadic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) functions and `**kwargs` allows "parameter-variadic" functions.